# Export Powershell find to .CSV file?

Tags: powershell, export

Currently I run this command to execute a find and write to a .txt file

`(gci -filter *.jpg -recurse).FullName > AllJPG.txt`

is there a simplified way to export this `(gci -filter *.jpg -recurse).FullName` to a .CSV>
Or how can I marry these two together

```
(gci -filter *.jpg -recurse).FullName > AllJPG.txt

Export-Csv 'AllJPG.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Part two is how to execute multiple searches in the same way and export each find to a separate .CSV file?

.jpg
.doc
.xls

Currently I run this

```
(gci -filter *.jpg -recurse).FullName > AllJPG.txt
(gci -filter *.xl* -recurse).FullName > AllExcel.txt
(gci -filter *.do* -recurse).FullName > AllWord.txt
```

Comment: `gci -filter *.jpg -recurse | select FullName | Export-Csv AllJPG.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture`

Comment: A CSV usually have multiple columns. You want a CSV with only one column (the `FullName` property value)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One column only with full path and file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jpg = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$doc = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$xls = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

Get-ChildItem -File -Include '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.doc*', '*.xls*' -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_
    switch -Wildcard ($item.Extension) {
        '.jp*g' { $jpg.Add($item) }
        '.doc*' { $doc.Add($item) }
        '.xls*' { $xls.Add($item) }
    }
}

$jpg | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Path 'AllJPG.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
$doc | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Path 'AllWord.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
$xls | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Path 'AllExcel.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

<sup>this way you can also export other file properties because the lists will contain the full FileInfo objects</sup>